# python printing a blank line on the first line when writing to a file

Tags: python, file, newline

I'm stuck on why my code is printing a blank line before writing text to a file.  What I am doing is reading two files from a zipped folder and writing the text to a new text file.  I am getting the expected results in the file, except for the fact that there is a blank line on the first line of the file.

```
def test():
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Zip_file.zip'):
        zf = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\Zip_file.zip')
        for filename in zf.namelist():
            with zf.open(filename, 'r') as f:
                words = io.TextIOWrapper(f)
                new_file = io.open(r'C:\Users\test\Desktop\new_file.txt', 'a')
                for line in words:
                    new_file.write(line)
                new_file.write('\n')
    else:
        pass

    zf.close()
    words.close()
    f.close()
    new_file.close()
```

Output in new_file (there is a blank line before the first "This is a test line...")

```
This is a test line...
This is a test line...
this is test #2
this is test #2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the first file in `zf.namelist()` doesn't contain anything, so you skip the `for line in words` loop for that file and just do `new_file.write('\n')`. It's difficult to tell without seeing the files that you're looping over; perhaps add some debug statements that print out the files' names and some info, e.g. their size.

Comment: I think you are right.  When I call zf.namelist() I get the following list. ['New folder/', 'New folder/test1.txt', 'New folder/test2.txt'].  New folder is the name of the folder in which the files are held.  I'll go back to the documentation to see if there is a good way around this.